# og:image being ignored when image URL is generated dynamically by php

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I have a web page (under Wordpress) for which I want to display a different preview image in Facebook posts depending on a query string parameter.

To do this, inside my `<head>` tag, I have:

```
<?php 
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $_GET['lbcid'] ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
?>

<meta property="og:url"                content="http://uat1.one-pager.sugarloafculinary.com/?lbcid=6957" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="Test Title" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="Description Here" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="<?php echo $image[0] ?>" />
```

`$image[0]` outputs a valid URL, but Facebook seems to be ignoring that `<meta>` tag altogether when the value of the `content` attribute is output dynamically by PHP. Instead it chooses the 1st image on the page that fits the requirements. I have gone into the FB debugging tool and re-scraped - this has no effect (on this issue).

When I hard code the value of the `content` attribute, it displays as expected. Ex:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://uat1.one-pager.sugarloafculinary.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/blog_bulgar-pudding.jpg" />
```

You can see this in action at http://uat1.one-pager.sugarloafculinary.com/?lbcid=6957. If you view the source, you'll see that there is a valid (dynamically generated) URL for an image in that `<meta>` tag, but if you test the page in the [FB Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/), you'll see that the specified image is not displayed.

Can anyone see any errors in my code? Is there some trick to getting this to work? Is it perhaps a Wordpress thing? (I haven't tested outside of WP).

**EDIT:**
See accepted answer below. Code at URLs above has been modified to resolve issue, so they will no longer illustrate the problem. Simple solution: it seems the FB scraper stops at the first instance of og:image, of which mine was 2nd and thus ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using facebook debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug it seems that image is generated successfully and facebook can read it

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://uat1.one-pager.sugarloafculinary.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/logo_horz1-e1530285280453.png" />
<!--this image is less than 200*200px -->
```

the error as debugger told is that image is less than 200px * 200px
if you use larger image that will fix the problem

> EDIT: after I revised the code I found MANY generated `og:image` on
>   code
>
> FB takes first one and ignores the rest. first `og:image` is small so
>   error occures
>
> revise your plugins and theme to eliminate unwanted `og:image`

Comment: that's the logo image, chosen by Facebook to use as the preview because it's ignoring my `<meta property="og:image...>` tag. If you look at the source, the correct image URL is http://uat1.one-pager.sugarloafculinary.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/front-pdf.jpg

Comment: I have found it
Have a look on your source. 
many `og:image` are on your page
FB takes first one which is small and ignores the rest

revise your plugins and theme to eliminate unwanted `og:image`

Comment: @Daveh0 I Edited the answer to fit solution